# Getting Started with APRS

Tags: aprs

The [APRS.org](http://aprs.org) web site provides some good information but is not very well organized and does not appear to be actively maintained. What are some good resources for beginners seeking the following:

1. Minimum equipment needed to receive packets
2. Minimum equipment needed to transmit packets
3. Best practices for test transmissions
4. Overall etiquette so as not to annoy the community
5. Modern (still active in 2013) community resources for discussing the APRS system

As a newly-minted tech, I thank you for your insight.

Comment: This question is a bit too broad for the Q&A format here - it'd make a good blog post or guide, but a question that touches on equipment, test transmissions, etiquette, and resources should really be split into multiple questions.

Comment: I recently posted a few articles on my blog about [implementing APRS](http://hugosprojects.wordpress.com/) if you're still interested.